# How to convert an integer from any base to any other base?

Tags: python, radix

I am trying to do something that will convert any base to any other base without using decimal converting.

For example program will ask from user:

```
"Please put number which you would like to convert: 101"

"Please write from which base you want to convert: 2 " #base(2)

"Please write to which base you want to convert: 6"   #base(6)

and will return value which converted from base(2) to base(6)

"Here is the result: 5"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't convert integers from one base to another. The integer doesn't change. You render an integer into a representation.

A normal (conventional) number is not, technically, a "decimal" number. It is a decimal representation of a number. Likewise for binary, octal, hexadecimal, etc.

For converting string representations of integers into any base between 2 and 36 you can simply use the int() built-in function with its extra (optional) argument. Python assumes a reasonably intuitive sequence of the letters 'a' through 'z' to represent "digits" greater than 9.

For example: `int('101101',2) -> 45` and `int('101101',3) -> 280` and so on.

For rendering an integer into binary, octal or hexadecimal one can simply use Python's built-in string formatting (though binary and perhaps octal were added sometime after version 2.2 of CPython ... and I don't remember the details).

It is, perhaps, not coincidental that Python's standard library definition of string.literal is returned in precisely the correct sequence to be used for any base up to 36 ... and one could, conceivably, use it to render integers into bases up through 99 ... though the notion of number representations where 'a' and 'A' are distinct digits along with spaces, newlines, etc. is a bit of a mind bender.

Comment: Base64 encoding is an example of a case-sensitive base system. An arbitrary binary stream is broken into 6-bit chunks, and each chunks written as a single digit in a base-64 representation: one variant uses `A = 0`, `B = 1`, ... `Z = 25`, `a = 26`, ..., `z = 51`, `0 = 52`, ... `9 = 61`, `+ = 62` and `/ = 63`. Other variants exist for applications that already have special meanings for `+` and/or `/`.

Comment: `You don't convert integers from one base to another. The integer doesn't change. You render an integer into a representation.` why? I don't understand, if I have an Integer say 101 in base 2 then I "convert" it to 5 in base 10 what is wrong in that?

Answer (score 0):

I have a naive approach, converting the number to base 10, our checkpoint, and then from ten.

```
def base(k,b,n):
  def to_ten(k,b):
    index = [
      '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'
      ]
    k = str(k)[::-1]
    r = 0
    for i in range(len(k)):
      r += (b**i)*int(index.index(k[i]))
    return r
  def from_base(k,b):
      r = ""
      while k>0:
          d = int(k%b)
          if d<10:
              r += str(d)
          else:
              r += chr(ord('A')+d-10)
          k //= b
      r = r[::-1]
      return r
  return from_base(to_ten(k,b),n)

k = input('Insert the number you\'d like to convert: ')
b = int(input('Insert the base you\'d like to convert ' + k + ' from: '))
n = int(input('Insert the base you\'d like to convert to: '))

print('Your answer is: ' + str(base(k,b,n)))
```

Please tell me if the code does not work.